# XSLT1.0 to generate CSV questions

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSLT to CSV conversion these are the following i know:

Scenario: Lets assume i am at A3 (Column A and Row 3 in csv/Excel)

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#xa;</xsl:text> ---> Jump to A4 from A3, ie go to next line
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">,</xsl:text> ----> Jump to B4 from A4, ie go to next column
```

What should i use to go from A4 directly to B1? ---> ie next column top

What should i use to go from A4 directly to B2, if B1 is already filled? ---> ie next column first empty row

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that - once a CSV line has been generated you cannot go back to it.

You have to write your XSLT so that it can generate the CSV lines in sequence, without having to 'jump back'.

If you post a sample of your XML input and XSL we can have a stab at helping you with that.